# I have form which takes huge texts equivalent to 4000 chars how to upload them into sfmc DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a form that takes input of huge length of data equivalent to 4000 chars in both the fields, what would be the best way to insert them into a sfmc data extension ?

Comment: Have you found limitations in the options under consideration? Are you just asking if you should use SSJS or AMPscript?

Comment: Saw one limitation like I cannot send the data to a processing page it's huge, throws 500 internal error on the processing page

Comment: If that's the case, please update your question to include the code that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create the DE from email > subscribers > DE

When you create the text field in the DE, to hold this large text, keep the text field length as blank. This will keep the text field as VARCHAR.

You can only do this from email studio. You can't do this from Contact Builder.

When you create such field, you can insert any number of characters in that field in the DE.

If the question is submitting the form, you can write perhaps use SSJS but not an expert there...